# Composite C1 log file issues - Folder growing too large

Tags: c1-cms

I am having trouble with one of my Composite C1 websites regarding log files. The log file folder just seems to be growing too large.

I have 20 sites all very similar and getting used similar. They are all around 50mb in total for the whole site which is fine. This particular site in question is 750mb and 700mb of that is just log files.

1. Should log files clear out after a certain amount of days?
2. Does anyone know why this might happen?
3. How might I go about disabling logging?
4. Is there any harm manually deleting log files?

Thanks

David

Answer (score 1):

1) Should log files clear out after a certain amount of days?

No, log auto clearing hasn't been implemented.

2) Does anyone know why this might happen?

Check the log file's content. Those are plain text files, you
can read them either from console (Top menu -> Tools -> Server Log), or using the log viewer tool

http://docs.composite.net/Configuration/Logging

There could be many reasons, most likely some of the functionality crashes and the related exception(s) are logged multiple times

3) How might I go about disabling logging?

You can remove "File logger" from the configuration file
~/App_Data/Composite/Composite.config

or choose only to log only exceptions.

http://docs.composite.net/Configuration/Logging/Enabling-Verbose-Logging

I recommend not to do it though, a stable site should be running without frequent exceptions and restarts, and should not produce too many log data

4) Is there any harm manually deleting log files?

No.

Answer (score 0):

I have C1 sites of 12 months with < 1MB logs.

Read them all - there are probably crashes happening that shouldn't be.